# Validating uploaded images

Tags: php, validation, image

I have attempted to write a method that checks that images being uploaded are valid.

```
public function checkValidImages(){
            $errors             = array();
            $allowedImages      = array('image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/png','img/gif');
            $maxFileSize        = 2097152;
            $invalidSize        = 0;
            $invalidTypes       = 0;
            $invalidDimension   = 0;
            $minWidth           = 220;
            $minHeight          = 220;

            // Check atleast one image has been selected
            foreach($_FILES['event-images']['tmp_name'] as $tmp_name){ 

                if($tmp_name == ""){
                    $errors[] = 'Please select atleast one image.'; // This is okay because instance would only occur once
                }
            }

            // Check Images are valid image types
            foreach($_FILES['event-images']['type'] as $type){ 

                if(!in_array($type, $allowedImages)){
                    $invalidTypes++;
                }
            }

            // Check images are valid sizes
            foreach($_FILES['event-images']['size'] AS $size){
                if($size > $maxFileSize){
                    $invalidSize++;
                }
            }

            // Check images are atleast 220px high and 220px wide
            foreach($_FILES['event-images']['tmp_name'] AS $image){

                // Get image width and height
                $image_dimensions = getimagesize($image); // returns an array of image info [0] = width, [1] = height
                $image_width = $image_dimensions[0]; // Image width
                $image_height = $image_dimensions[1]; // Image height

                if(($image_width < $minWidth) || ($image_height < $minHeight)){
                    $invalidDimension++;
                }
            }

            // Add errors to return array
            if($invalidDimension > 0){
                $errors[] = 'One or more of your images has invalid dimensions. Images must be atleast 220px by 220px.';
            }
            if($invalidTypes > 0){
                $errors[] = 'One or more of your images has an invalid image type. Please only select jpg, png or gif images.';
            }
            if($invalidSize > 0){
                $errors[] = 'One or more of your images is an invalid size. Please only select images less than 2MB in size.';
            }

            // Return errors
            return $errors;
        }
```

I was wondering if this could be made cleaner or more efficient.

Comment: You're not doing any check for exploits nor managing duplicates

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 foreach loops for the same files, going for a little more complex but more
organaized nested loop would be better, like this

```
foreach ($_FILES['event-images']['tmp_name'] as $tmp_name) {
    if (!empty($tmp_name)){
        $image = $_FILES["event-images"]["name"];
        $path_info = pathinfo($image);
        if ($path_info['extension'] == 'jpg' || $path_info['extension'] == 'jpeg' || $path_info['extension'] == 'png' || $path_info['extension'] == 'gif'){
            if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] <= $maxFileSize){
                $image_d = getimagesize($image);            
                if(($image_d[0] >= $minWidth) && ($image_d[1] >= $minHeight)){
                    $errors[]="valid image";
                }else{
                    $errors[]="invalid dimension";
                }
            }else{
                $errors[]="invalid file size";
            }
        }else{
            $errors[]="format not supported";
        }

    }else{
        $errors[] = 'Please select at least one image.';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This builds on @Rajarshi answer, but simplifies the nesting (in my opinion)

```
foreach ($_FILES['event-images']['tmp_name'] as $tmp_name) {

    if (empty($tmp_name)){
        $errors[] = 'Please select at least one image.';
        continue;
    }

    $image = $_FILES["event-images"]["name"];
    $path_info = pathinfo($image);

    if (!is_valid_filetype($path_info['extension']) {
        $errors[]="format not supported";
        continue;
    }

    if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > $maxFileSize){
        $errors[]="invalid file size";
        continue;
    }

    $image_d = getimagesize($image);            
    if(($image_d[0] < $minWidth) || ($image_d[1] < $minHeight)){
        $errors[]="invalid dimension";
        continue;
    }

    // why return an error for a valid image?
    //$errors[]="valid image";
}


function is_valid_filetype($ext) {
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    return in_array($ext, array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'));
}
```